# How to retain content type of file in Github?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, github-pages, mime-types

Committed a gzip compressed data *.tgz to GitHub. But when I downloaded the file from Git `wget https://github.com/org/charts/releases/download/chart-1.0.0/chart-1.0.0.tgz`, Content-Type coming as `text/html`.
How do I retain the file content type in GitHub? `.gitattributes` can help here?

Comment: The url you mention does not point at a file stored in git, it is an archive generated by github. You won't find your answer in `git`, check `github`'s doc (on release archives probably).

Comment: @LeGEC, Thats a private repo. Can't make it public because of company policy.

Comment: I completely understand. My comment meant : it is not a `git` issue. It has to do with how `github` serves its release archives.

Comment: Look at [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/228412/270277). The problem is not about the fact that it is a compressed file. It is a general problem with downloading any file from GitHub. Answers to that question should solve your problem.

Comment: [This gist](https://gist.github.com/jwebcat/5122366) may also be helpful.

Comment: file extension is a problem here? I don't see any mime-type set for .tgz file at https://github.com/jshttp/mime-db